# Cross-thread operation not valid in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the-t)

Greeting,
I'm trying to update button status from a thread and I'm getting this error:

"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'btn1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

please advice how to fix this problem.

here is my code:

```
 if (strMyPlayer == "Player One")
 {
      if (srReceiver.ReadLine() == "Player One says: btn1")
      {
           btn1.Text = "O";
           btn1.Enabled = false; 
      }
 }
 else
 {
      if (srReceiver.ReadLine() == "btn1")
      {
           btn1.Text = "X";
           btn1.Enabled = false;
      }     
 }
```

Comment: there are at least **20** same questions, also first result in google query will give you solution. I really would like to hear why didn't you do any attempts to find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [Control.InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) and one of [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) / [Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update a UI element from a background thread. I'm guessing srReceiver runs on a background thread.

You can update it using a delegate:

```
btn1.Invoke(delegate {
                             btn1.Enabled = "OK";
                             btn1.Text = "X";
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe use the invoke-function to run the function on the controls thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(VS.71).aspx